# Speed up to offset in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table with about 70000000 rows of phone numbers. I use `OFFSET` to read those 50 by 50 numbers.

But it takes a long time (about 1 min).

However, that full-text index used for search and does not impact for offset.

How I can speed up my query?

```
SELECT *
FROM tblPhoneNumber
WHERE CountryID = @CountryID
ORDER BY ID
OFFSET ((@NumberCount - 1) * @PackageSize) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PackageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Why are you only reading it in batches of 50? Can you make the rows per batch higher?

Comment: yes ! But I want read 50 by 50 ! for example 50 number from USA 50 number from India and ...

Comment: So you want to select 50 rows for each country.  Would it be okay to do it all at once?

Comment: Are you reading **all** rows for a country in chunks of 50 rows? If so looks like a case for an API cursor http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68280/3690

Answer (score 0):

Throw a sequence on that table, index it and fetch ranges by sequence.  You could alternatively just use the ID column.

```
select *
    FROM tblPhoneNumber
    WHERE 
        CountryID = @CountryID
        and Sequence between @NumberCount and (@NumberCount + @PackageSize)
```

If you're inserting/deleting frequently, this can leave gaps, so depending on the code that utilizes these batches of numbers, this might be a problem, but in general a few gaps here and there may not be a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CROSS APPLY instead of OFFSET FETCH and do it all in one go. I grab TOP 2 to show you that you can grab any number of rows.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblPhoneNumber') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tblPhoneNumber;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Country') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Country;

CREATE TABLE #tblPhoneNumber (ID INT, Country VARCHAR(100), PhoneNumber INT);
CREATE TABLE #Country (Country VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #Country
VALUES ('USA'),('UK');

INSERT INTO #tblPhoneNumber
VALUES  (1,'USA',11111),
        (2,'USA',22222),
        (3,'USA',33333),
        (4,'UK',44444),
        (5,'UK',55555),
        (6,'UK',66666);     

SELECT *
FROM #Country
CROSS APPLY(
                SELECT TOP (2) ID,Country,PhoneNumber --Just change to TOP(50) for your code
                FROM #tblPhoneNumber
                WHERE #Country.Country = #tblPhoneNumber.Country
            ) CA
```